# Direct proof with Trig Identity

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

Prove $\int_0^L\cos(n\pi x/L)\cos(k\pi x/L)dx = \begin{cases} 
      0 & n \neq k \\
     L & n=0 \\
     \frac{L}{2} & n=k=1,2,3,\dots 
   \end{cases}$ using the identity

$\cos(A)\cos(B) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \cos(A-B) + \cos(A+B) \right)$

I started with the case $n=0$ and I have already run into a problem.

I get $\int_0^L\cos(k\pi x/L)dx$ then $\left.\sin(\pi x k/L)\frac{L}{\pi k}\right|_0^L$ which becomes $sin(\pi k) L / (\pi k)$. How does this become $L$?

For $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ it is zero, so I don't understand and I don't believe I made a mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the second answer should be for $n = k = 0$. And then it's just the integral from $0$ to $L$ of $\cos(0)\cos(0) = 1$. So it's evidently $L$.

BTW: a clue that it should be $n = k = 0$: if it really worked for arbitrary $k$, say $k = 1$, then the first and second lines would be giving different values for the single case $n = 0, k = 1$.

Comment: hmmm... perhaps there was a typo. It does say n=0. I will use the n=k=0 though thank you!